# use node script instead of bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I have a file call .deploy and here is the content

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@201.189.46.12
```

which is to log in to my cloud server. I did this because I don't want to remember the api. So to go to my server I will do

`bash .deploy`

but instead of using bash, can I have other alternative? Other developer might using other OS.

Answer (score 0):

This might work using [node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh), although I didn't see much documentation of how to use its `requestShell` function:

```
var path, node-ssh, ssh, fs
fs = require('fs')
path = require('path')
node-ssh = require('node-ssh')
ssh = new node-ssh()
ssh.connect({
  host: '(hostname or ip address goes here)',
  username: 'root'
  /* can also use privateKey parameter to specify a RSA key file instead of password */
  password,
    tryKeyboard: true,
    /* workaround bug in ssl2 https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/604 */
    onKeyboardInteractive: (name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) => {
        if (prompts.length > 0 && prompts[0].prompt.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
          finish([password])
        }
      }
  })
})
.then(function() {
  ssh.requestShell()
})
```

Alternative with [simple-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh):

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh')
var readline = require('readline')
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin
    output: process.stdout
})

var ssh = new SSH({
    host: '(hostname or ip address goes here)'
    user: 'root'
    pass: 'your password'  
})
rl.on('line', function(input) {
    ssh.exec(input, {
      out: function(stdout) {
        console.log(stdout)
      }
      err: function(stderr) {
        console.log(stderr)
      }
    }).start()  
}).on('close', function() {
      process.exit(0)
})
```